# How to parse string using a JSGF grammar in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, grammar

I am doing speech recognition using CMU Sphinx.

CMU Sphinx uses JSGF grammar to do speech recognition. It has its own JSGF parser: `edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.parser.JSGFParser`, but I think it is used to parse a JSGF file, not to parse a text according to a JSGF grammar. Am I right?

I also looked into `javax.speech.recognition` which provides a `RuleGrammar` class with a `parse` method. It seems it would solve the problem, but I don't feel it is appropriate to import a whole speech recognition package, just to use its parser.

Is there a better way to parse a text using JSGF?

Additionally, I would like the solution to provide a way to retrieve JSGF tags.

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: @alanturing If I remember well, I needed to do this to use the parse tree for natural language processing. But I ended up just detecting keywords in the sentences instead. So short answer is no.